Ways to keep files in /tmp?
I have a RHEL 8 workstation that hosts an app whose GUI is accessible through https.
When the app is started, it creates a few socket files in /tmp with random names and the .sock suffix:
$ ls -l /tmp/*.sock
srwx------ 1 app app 0 Dec 21 13:30 /tmp/supervisor-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock
srwx------ 1 app app 0 Dec 21 13:31 /tmp/mongodb-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock
srwx------ 1 app app 0 Dec 21 13:31 /tmp/livegui-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock

$ file /tmp/*.sock
/tmp/supervisor-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock: socket
/tmp/mongodb-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock:    socket
/tmp/livegui-358513b0f6222d2339e4ab66d30b0037.sock:    socket

update: The "random" part of the socket filenames is in fact a MD5 of the path where the app is installed.
When people use the app frequently, the app works fine for weeks/months, but when nobody connects to the app for a few days, it stops responding; when that happens I can see that the .sock files got deleted while the app processes are still running...
Is there any way to prevent the deletion of some files in /tmp?

You need some variant of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511128/70524

Are you saying the files are deleted without the machine restarting? Or is there a restart in the middle somewhere?

@terdon The app processes are still running (at least they show with ps) but the files in /tmp disappeared, which makes it dysfunctional and impossible to restart (until the processes are killed by hand)

OK, so that means the machine did NOT restart in the meantime, right? That's what I'm asking.

This sounds a bit strange. If the app is still running, then it can simply keep the files open. Sure, the links will be deleted, but the files will still be there. Note that FHS says that apps may not assume that files in /tmp persist between invocations of the app. If the app is part of the distribution, /run/ would be a more appropriate place to store those files. If it isn't, may /var/tmp does the trick.

@JörgWMittag, those are sockets. If their names are deleted, they can't be connected to, even if they might still exist in the process that created them.

@ilkkachu: Indeed, they are! Somehow, my brain read "sockets" but registered "PID files".

Yes, see man 5 tmpfiles.d: then create a configuration file e.g. /etc/tmpfiles.d/myappsocket.conf with the contents like:
X /tmp/*.sock

With that, the temporary file manager process should no longer delete your application socket.

It is slightly odd that this would be needed, though; I recall systemd-tmpfiles has had code to check sockets against /proc/net so that still-bound ones would be automatically excluded.

That will exclude any .sock file in /tmp; if I want to restrict the rule to the .sock owned by the app user, should I use X /tmp/*.sock - app app - -?

@ilkkachu thanks for the correction, it looks like I mistyped the asterisk on my new mobile phone.

@Fravadona according to the version of the man page on my system, the configuration entry type X does not accept username/group parameters, but only the age parameter. If your system's man page says something different, then you should trust that instead.

@telcoM the man page shows #Type Path Mode UID  GID Age Argument for the configuration format

Yes, and for many types, including x and X, there are - signs in the Mode, UID and GID fields, indicating that those are not applicable for this type of entry. On the man page of my system, the text descriptions on the UID/GID parameters confirms that "These parameters are ignored for x, r, R, L, t and a lines" but does not mention X specifically - I assume this is just a documentation omission but feel free to test it.

@telcoM It's the same for me... As the ownership can't be used to differentiate the .sock files in /tmp I looked into the scripts of the app. The "random" part in the socket filenames is in fact the MD5 of the installation path; that means that the filenames won't change and I can use them directly in the configuation file of tmpfiles.

The preferred resolution is for the app to instead put the socket under /run, because that’s where the standards for this type of thing (note the final line of section 3.15.2) say that such things should be (both because they are not temporary data, and because no sane system cleans out old files in /run except on a reboot).
The least preferred, but still workable, resolution is to add an exception for systemd-tmpfiles in /etc/tmpfiles.d to exclude the files from cleanup as suggested by the answer by telcoM.
Alternatively to both options, and significantly more complicated, would be to have the app itself write out overrides for the specific socket paths in a file in /run/tmpfiles.d once it knows what the paths are.
Irrespective of all of that though, this is a bug that should be reported to the app developers (and possibly the systemd developers, because systemd-tmpfiles shouldn’t be removing listening sockets, though I’m not sure when it started avoiding doing so, so that may just be a result of the version of systemd on RHEL 8).

I wrote my answer on a mobile phone, so I decided just to answer the question and omit pondering the root causes; but I agree, depending on further details, either the application's or systemd-tmpfiles's behavior (or maybe even both) would qualify as bugs.

While I can make a request to the devs for the app to use a dir in /run, creating that dir will need elevated privileges, at least at install time; so I'm not sure the devs will make that modification, as the app currently have no requirement for root access rights.

@Fravadona Systemd itself provides handling for this, if you actually set up a proper service unit for the service. The relevant key is RuntimeDir=, which will make sure the directory exists and has the right permissions before the service itself gets started. Alternatively, you could also just add a config entry for systemd-tmpfiles to create the directory at boot.

@Fravadona: If it's a desktop app that only has a regular user's privileges, then it should instead use $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, i.e. /run/user/<uid>, which is meant to be the per-user equivalent of /run overall.

@grawity And, notably, is functionally guaranteed to exist within a user session for the user with the associated UID on any system using systemd, and almost any system using elogind with another init system.

@grawity unfortunately XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn't set for the app user and I can only see 0 in /run/user/ and /var/run/user/

@Fravadona How is the app launched? Via systemctl? Via sudo or su?

@grawity mostly ssh appuser@rhel8 appcmd start

@Fravadona That would explain why XDG_RUNTIME_DIR isn’t set, you don’t get an actual session when using an explicit command like that with SSH. But if you can’t manage the app as a regular system service, that’s a huge issue. I highly encourage you to look into how to write systemd service files so you can write one for this app, because it’s sounding like that will not only solve your issue, but also make your life much simpler.

@AustinHemmelgarn Well, initially I set the app as a systemd service - not for the reasons you mentioned above but just to make it start at boot time - then the users started complaining they couldn't use the app as in the docs and tutorials... so I dropped systemd and did a "standard" setup. Now some problems pop up sometimes but overall I don't have to intervene as often as back then.

@Fravadona Well, if that's what you're doing, I would recommend at least running sudo loginctl enable-linger appuser once, to mark that user account as "keep active even if logged out" in systemd – it'll both create a permanent /run/user/UID and might avoid some other problems. (It'll also let you define a user-level systemd service at ~/.config/systemd/user/ in case that works any better, since the 'linger' flag makes that user's default.target start on boot too.)

@grawity That's worth giving it a shot indeed

put them in /var/run/user/UID/  instead

/tmp seams hard to change: grep -FRI '/tmp' /.../app | wc -l => 12882 and  grep -FRI 'TMPDIR' /.../app | wc -l => 0

if no source contact vendor for assisitance, requst app comply with FHS

The app should support TMPDIR, and you should contact them to have it do so in the next version(s). And also: using /tmp to store sockets is not correct, they should probably use /run (formerly /var/run, but deprecated) instead, or a subdirectory of /run.

A workaround that doesn't require elevated privileges would be to regularly update the access times of the .sock files using the crontab of the user that runs the app processes.
Example of crontab entry for updating the access times of the /tmp/*.sock files everyday at 01:00 AM:
0 1 * * * touch -ac /tmp/*.sock

